# Upgrade ruby sub dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails application that has the following dependency structure:

```
actionview (6.1.6.1)
  rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
    loofah (2.18.0)
```

I'd like to get loofah to `2.19.1` without updating actionview. Is it possible to upgrade just the transitive dependency versions without changing the version of actionview?

Answer (score 2):

I would run

```
bundle update loofah
```

to only update the `loofah` gem without toughing other dependencies if not needed.

See [Updating a Gem Without Modifying the Gemfile](https://bundler.io/guides/updating_gems.html#updating-a-gem-without-modifying-the-gemfile).

Comment: This is actually exactly how it is recommended in the `rails-html-sanitizer` gem [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/v1.4.3/rails-html-sanitizer.gemspec#L28) *NOTE: There's no need to update this dependency for Loofah CVEs in minor releases when users can simply run `bundle update loofah`"*